VSCode No Warnings shown
When writing a .tex file I normally get warnings in the problems for like "overfull hbox" or "missing } in line 12".
Now I just see nothing - any ideas?
When using chktex to check the errors/warnings I still find some.
Any help?

The warnings should still be found in the .log file that is generated by TeX

Yes but I am missing the highlighting in the code @JasperHabicht

I think, it also depends on the extension you are using.
